# Can anybody help me solve this following error: "list index out of range"?

Tags: python, opencv

Can any body solve the error:
I was trying to segment ROI which contains digits.
The code worked for some of the images. But for others it shows the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-1a8d1317985a> in <module>
      1 #segment digits from images in Marks folder
----> 2 digits_in_cell("./Cropped/Marks/")

<ipython-input-57-8fe190745c08> in digits_in_cell(cropped_dir_path)
     23             cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     24 
---> 25         cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
     26 
     27         orig = cell.copy()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

```
    i=7
    cell = cv2.imread(str(i) + '.png')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(cell, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)
    # threshold the image
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray ,112,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.imshow("Image", thresh1) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # dilate the white portions
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh1, None, iterations=5)
    cv2.imshow("Image", dilate) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # find contours in the image
    cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilate.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]

    orig = cell.copy()


    #for cnt in cnts:
        # Check the area of contour, if it is very small ignore it
        #if(cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 100):
         #   continue

        # Filtered countours are detected
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts)

    # Taking ROI of the cotour
    roi = cell[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Mark them on the image if you want
    cv2.rectangle(orig,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    # Save your contours or characters
    cv2.imwrite("roi" + str(i) + ".png", roi)

    i = i + 1 

    cv2.imshow("Image", orig) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution of the line

```
cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours
```

returns an empty list for `cnts` variable. It just means the the function dind't find any contours, but on the next line, you are asking for the first of them, hence the error.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why some of the contors are detected and some of them are not?

Comment: if all the pixels in your input image bigger than 112 or all are smaller than 112 there is no contour after thresholding with that value. Can you upload thresh1 and dilate images for the input that failed?